# Запись массива структур в базу в бинарном виде

Tags: c, postgresql

Не могу найти как без перевода в текст послать данные в постгрес.
Все столбцы структуры имеют форматы `uint8_t`,`uint16_t`,`uint32_t`. В таблице столбцы имеют соответствующий типы.

Задача отправить 4000 строк из сишного массива в INSERT.

Comment: а почему  не хотите переводить в текст? я бы просто сгенерировал sql файл  с текстом на вставку и потом просто применил уже на сервере.

Comment: вся программка занимает 205 строчек включая комменты и пустые.. (там приём и парсинг udp ). переводить числа в строку займет большую часть времени процессора. тогда придется сооружать потоки, чтоб не блокировать приём данных. хотелось остаться в одном потоке пока.

Comment: у Вас там миллионы записей в секунду? Вы скороее упретесь в базу, чем в перевод в строку. printf достаточно быстрый.

Comment: @KoVadim базу то балансировать можно.

Comment: @KoVadim да и объем трафика возрастает... хотелось бы максимально оптимизировать для запуска на армах

Comment: Похоже, Вы занялись классической задачей - преждевременной оптимизацией. И пытаетесь сэкономить на спичках при наличии базы. 
Я предлагаю два варианта - либо писать по сети на промежуточное приложение, которое уже будет в базу вкладывать, либо сохранять на в файл в бинарном виде. А когда данные будут нужны - вот там уже и расспакуете. В любом случае - напишите для начала "наивно",  текстовыми строками и посмотрите - может Вам скорости хватит.

Comment: @KoVadim сейчас на питоне, работает неплохо, но хочется большего.

Comment: Если БД предоставляет API, то можно им пользоваться.

Comment: postgresql, указанна в вопросе

Comment: @eri, именно с postgres я так и поступаю: генерирую строки для `COPY`, порциями по тыщонке записей. Объёмы - десятки миллионов вставок. Не нужно тут париться с бинарностью. А уж когда их *всего* тысячи - тем более.

Comment: *переводить числа в строку займет большую часть времени процессора* -- вы уже это отпрофилировали, или теоретически рассуждаете?

Comment: остальной код - два malloc один memcpy и несколько приведений типов

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно, что вы подразумеваете под бинарным видом. Вам нужно сериализовать все поля структуры в BLOB? Обычно поля структур соответствуют полям таблицы базы данных. Приведите описание таблицы в базе данных и описание вашей структуры.

Comment: @maestro я имею ввиду передачу структуры без сериализации. например структура с 2мя интами - 8 байт. вот эти 8 байт кинуть и они также рядышком положились в файлы базы.

Comment: @eri, положить два инта в массив 8 байт - это и есть сериализация! И всё же я хочу увидеть схему БД. Как вы их там будете хранить? В BLOB?

Answer (score 2):

Вашу структуру вам в любом случае придётся переводить в строковое представление, потому что любой SQL-запрос - это строка.

Давайте подключим телепатию и попробуем определить вашу задачу. Допустим, у вас есть такая структура:

```
struct TwoInts {
    uint32_t int1;
    uint32_t int2;
};
```

Предположим, вы хотите сериализовать эту структуру в массив байт, а массив байт в дальнейшем записать в такую таблицу PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ints (
   id int,
   field bytea
);
```

Чтобы составить SQL-запрос, который запишет вашу структуру в базу данных, используйте следующий код:

```
char query[100];
struct TwoInts a = {44, 55};
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO ints (id, field) VALUES(0, decode('%08X%08X', 'hex'))", a.int1, a.int2);
```

В результате в массив query запишется следующая строка:

```
INSERT INTO ints (id, field) VALUES(0, decode('000000210000002C', 'hex'));
```

Осталось только отправить эту строку драйверу SQL, чтобы запрос выполнился.

Но я до сих пор не понимаю, почему вы не хотите записывать числа в отдельные поля базы данных!

Comment: я хотел в отдельные поля. но всеравно спасибо за ответ

Comment: @eri, так вы же писали, что в базу данных нужно записать структуру из 2 интов - 8 байт! А теперь пишете, что в отдельные поля. Так объясните же нормально, чего вы хотите! И если вы всё-таки собираетесь хранить цифры в отдельных полях, то нет никакого смысла переводить 1 инт в 4 байта, так как при хранении данных в формате BLOB у вас не будет возможности задавать условия в выборке данных. Гораздо проще хранить инт как инт. И, как я уже сказал, от перевода в строковое представление вам не уйти.

Comment: `Все столбцы структуры имеют форматы uint8_t,uint16_t,uint32_t. В таблице столбцы имеют соответствующий типы.`

Comment: @eri, Этого не может быть, потому что в PostgreSQL [нет типов](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html), соответствующих uint8_t, uint16_t,uint32_t.

Comment: да, только со знаком. но один бит роли особо не игает

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что Вам поможет использование т.н. пользовательских переменных.

[Использование пользовательских переменных](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-user-variables.html)

В двух словах:

- SQL запрос в символьном виде передаётся на сервер однократно и там
  запоминается
- Этот подготовленный запрос можно использовать
  многократно, не повторяя разбор запроса
- Конкретные значения констант
  вставляются в запрос из связанных переменных, без преобразования их в
  символьный формат.

Пример по ссылке не совсем подходит к Вашей задаче, но я думаю - идея понятна!

Answer (score 0):

Если не мудрить и сделать нормально, то попробуйте так. Вот ваша структура:

```
struct TwoInts {
    uint32_t int1;
    uint32_t int2;
};
```

Вот ваша таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE ints (
   id int,
   int1 int,
   int2 int
);
```

Вот код формирования запроса:

```
char query[100];
struct TwoInts a = {44, 55};
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO ints (id, int1, int2) VALUES(0, %d, %d);", int1, int2);
```

Код сформирует следующий запрос:

```
INSERT INTO ints (id, int1, int2) VALUES(0, 44, 55);
```

p.s. Тут писали про подготовленные запросы, и их использование более безопасно. Вы можете их использовать, если ваш драйвер их поддерживает. Если нет, то вы можете реализовать их самостоятельно. Для этого нужно будет сначала отправить подготовленный запрос на сервер, где вместо действительных числовых параметров указать какой-то заполнитель. Сервер вернёт вам номер сохранённого запроса. В дальнейшем при вставке данных в таблицу вы отправляете серверу номер сохранённого запроса и набор параметров.

Comment: в libpq есть метод с $1,$2... и указателем

Answer (score 0):

Ответы и коментарии очень полезны, но цель в другом. Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

Для записи бинарных данных можно воспользоваться командой [COPY](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-copy)

На вход она принимает файл или поток (stdin, stdout), в случае libpq на указатель. С файлом всё предельно просто, а с потоком надо еще поэкспериментировать.

Входной файл имеет простую структуру:

```
cat /tmp/tmpfile | od -c | head
0000000   P   G   C   O   P   Y  \n 377  \r  \n  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \f  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0 001  \0  \0  \0
0000040 004  \0  \0  \0 001  \0  \0  \0  \b  \0 001 221 330 306   %   0
0000060  \0 377 377 377 377  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000100 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000120 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0  \0 377 377 377
0000140 377  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0
0000160  \0  \0  \f  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0 002  \0  \0  \0 004  \0
0000200  \0  \0 002  \0  \0  \0  \b  \0 001 221 330 306   %   0  \0 377
0000220 377 377 377  \0  \0  \0 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 004  \0
```

Заголовок и данные в сыром виде - почти то что нужно.
Этот формат [рекомендуется](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html) для загрузки большого объема данных.

Подготовленный блок можно загрузить:

```
postgres = PQsetdbLogin("localhost","5432","","","base","postgres","");
if (PQstatus(postgres) != CONNECTION_OK)
{ return 1; }
res = PQexec(postgres, "COPY tablename FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT binary)");
if (PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_COPY_IN ) {
    PQputCopyData(postgres, pgbuffer, size);
    PQputCopyEnd(postgres, NULL);
};
PQendcopy(postgres);
free(pgbuffer);
```